# Can not install Ruby 2.2.3 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I have the following problem with installation Ruby on Ubuntu via RVM: http://pastebin.com/VikBZmwR

Can anybody help me?

---

I am trying to install Ruby 2.2.3 using rbenv on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.

but i got different error.

I am attaching screen shot of terminal and error log here for more detail.

1. Terminal screen
   [image]
2. Error Log
   [image]

Comment: Can you execute `sudo apt-get update` and show us the output? Most probably some of the repositories you have defined are not reachable.

Comment: @panmari Yes, here: http://pastebin.com/yusnQrv3

Answer (score 1):

The error messages from `sudo apt-get update` are preventing you from using rvm effectively. For every error such as

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
```

check the files `/etc/apt/sources.list` or any file with the endig `.list` in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for the corresponding line and adapt or delete it there (These errors are caused by trying to reach not existing update mirrors).

Once you can run `sudo apt-get update` without getting any errors, installing a ruby through rvm will succeed again.